# PIP dependency conflicts when upgrading to Airflow

Tags: python, pip, airflow

I'm trying to upgrade Airflow to the Latest version by following the steps here - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/upgrading-from-1-10/index.html

Everything went well untill I executed this command -

```
pip install -U apache-airflow
```

Result of above command :

```
Requirement already satisfied: apache-airflow in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (1.10.15)
Collecting apache-airflow
  Downloading apache_airflow-2.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (5.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.3 MB 22.5 MB/s            
Requirement already satisfied: cattrs<1.1.0,>=1.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs<21.0,>=20.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from apache-airflow) (20.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown<4.0,>=2.5.2 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.6.11)
Collecting cryptography>=0.9.3
  Using cached cryptography-36.0.1-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.8 MB)
Collecting importlib-resources~=5.2
  Downloading importlib_resources-5.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: lockfile>=0.12.2 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.12.2)
Collecting dataclasses
  Downloading dataclasses-0.8-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting tenacity>=6.2.0
  Downloading tenacity-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setproctitle<2,>=1.1.8 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.1.10)
Collecting httpx<0.20.0
  Downloading httpx-0.19.0-py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 77 kB 8.1 MB/s             
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=1.7 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.1.3)
Collecting apache-airflow-providers-ftp
  Downloading apache_airflow_providers_ftp-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting python3-openid~=3.2
  Downloading python3_openid-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 133 kB 68.9 MB/s            
Requirement already satisfied: flask<2.0,>=1.1.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-login<0.5,>=0.3 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.4.1)
Collecting inflection>=0.3.1
  Downloading inflection-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.5 kB)
Collecting marshmallow-oneofschema>=2.0.1
  Downloading marshmallow_oneofschema-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Collecting flask-caching<2.0.0,>=1.5.0
  Downloading Flask_Caching-1.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting python-daemon>=2.2.4
  Downloading python_daemon-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: graphviz>=0.12 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema~=3.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-nvd3~=0.15.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.15.0)
Collecting sqlalchemy-jsonfield~=1.0
  Downloading SQLAlchemy_JSONField-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: markupsafe>=1.1.1 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.1.1)
Collecting werkzeug>=1.0.1,~=1.0
  Downloading Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 298 kB 50.4 MB/s            
Requirement already satisfied: python-slugify<5.0,>=3.0.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from apache-airflow) (4.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tabulate<0.9,>=0.7.5 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.8.6)
Collecting apache-airflow-providers-http
  Downloading apache_airflow_providers_http-2.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting sqlalchemy>=1.3.18
  Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.4.31-cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.6 MB 73.3 MB/s            
Requirement already satisfied: unicodecsv>=0.14.1 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.14.1)
Collecting apache-airflow-providers-sqlite
  Downloading apache_airflow_providers_sqlite-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=14.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from apache-airflow) (21.3)
Collecting pendulum~=2.0
  Downloading pendulum-2.1.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (154 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 154 kB 79.3 MB/s            
Requirement already satisfied: cached-property~=1.5 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: croniter<1.1,>=0.3.17 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.3.30)
Requirement already satisfied: lazy-object-proxy in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2<4,>=2.10.1 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.10.3)
Collecting clickclick>=1.2
  Downloading clickclick-20.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.4 kB)
Collecting apache-airflow-providers-imap
  Downloading apache_airflow_providers_imap-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.7.4 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from apache-airflow) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: colorlog<6.0,>=4.0.2 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (4.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: wtforms<3.0.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.2.1)
Collecting swagger-ui-bundle>=0.0.2
  Downloading swagger_ui_bundle-0.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (6.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 6.2 MB 52.5 MB/s            
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous<2.0,>=1.1.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil<6.0.0,>=4.2.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (5.6.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments<3.0,>=2.0.1 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: argcomplete~=1.10 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.10.2)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils<0.17 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.15.2)
Collecting alembic<2.0,>=1.5.1
  Downloading alembic-1.7.6-py3-none-any.whl (210 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 210 kB 55.3 MB/s            
Requirement already satisfied: pep562~=1.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.1)
Collecting flask-appbuilder<4.0.0,>=3.3.2
  Downloading Flask_AppBuilder-3.4.4-py3-none-any.whl (1.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.9 MB 67.7 MB/s            
Collecting flask-wtf<0.15,>=0.14.3
  Downloading Flask_WTF-0.14.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: iso8601>=0.1.12 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.1.12)
Collecting openapi-spec-validator>=0.2.4
  Downloading openapi_spec_validator-0.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting gunicorn>=20.1.0
  Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 79 kB 4.1 MB/s             
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3,>=2.3 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.8.1)
Collecting rich>=9.2.0
  Downloading rich-11.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (217 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 217 kB 57.9 MB/s            
Requirement already satisfied: dill<0.4,>=0.2.2 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.3.1.1)
Collecting blinker
  Downloading blinker-1.4.tar.gz (111 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 111 kB 54.1 MB/s            
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=5.1 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (5.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyjwt<2 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Mako in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from alembic<2.0,>=1.5.1->apache-airflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=4.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from clickclick>=1.2->apache-airflow) (7.0)
Collecting cffi>=1.12
  Using cached cffi-1.15.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (405 kB)
Collecting apispec[yaml]<4,>=3.3
  Downloading apispec-3.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting marshmallow<4,>=3
  Downloading marshmallow-3.14.1-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 47 kB 8.6 MB/s             
Requirement already satisfied: prison<1.0.0,>=0.2.1 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from flask-appbuilder<4.0.0,>=3.3.2->apache-airflow) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-SQLAlchemy<3,>=2.4 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<4.0.0,>=3.3.2->apache-airflow) (2.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: marshmallow-enum<2,>=1.5.1 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<4.0.0,>=3.3.2->apache-airflow) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy-utils<1,>=0.32.21 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from flask-appbuilder<4.0.0,>=3.3.2->apache-airflow) (0.38.2)
Requirement already satisfied: email-validator<2,>=1.0.5 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from flask-appbuilder<4.0.0,>=3.3.2->apache-airflow) (1.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-OpenID<2,>=1.2.5 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<4.0.0,>=3.3.2->apache-airflow) (1.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-JWT-Extended<4,>=3.18 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<4.0.0,>=3.3.2->apache-airflow) (3.24.1)
Collecting marshmallow-sqlalchemy<0.27.0,>=0.22.0
  Downloading marshmallow_sqlalchemy-0.26.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama<1,>=0.3.9 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<4.0.0,>=3.3.2->apache-airflow) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-Babel<3,>=1 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from flask-appbuilder<4.0.0,>=3.3.2->apache-airflow) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=3.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gunicorn>=20.1.0->apache-airflow) (41.6.0)
Collecting charset-normalizer
  Downloading charset_normalizer-2.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting async-generator
  Downloading async_generator-1.10-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting sniffio
  Downloading sniffio-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting httpcore<0.14.0,>=0.13.3
  Downloading httpcore-0.13.7-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 58 kB 11.1 MB/s            
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from httpx<0.20.0->apache-airflow) (2019.9.11)
Collecting rfc3986[idna2008]<2,>=1.3
  Downloading rfc3986-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=1.7->apache-airflow) (0.6.0)
Collecting zipp>=0.5
  Downloading zipp-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from jsonschema~=3.0->apache-airflow) (0.15.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jsonschema~=3.0->apache-airflow) (1.13.0)
Collecting jsonschema~=3.0
  Downloading jsonschema-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 56 kB 8.5 MB/s             
Collecting openapi-schema-validator<0.2.0
  Downloading openapi_schema_validator-0.1.6-py3-none-any.whl (7.9 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from packaging>=14.0->apache-airflow) (3.0.7)
Collecting pytzdata>=2020.1
  Downloading pytzdata-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (489 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 489 kB 66.7 MB/s            
Requirement already satisfied: text-unidecode>=1.3 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from python-slugify<5.0,>=3.0.0->apache-airflow) (1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python3-openid~=3.2->apache-airflow) (0.6.0)
Collecting commonmark<0.10.0,>=0.9.0
  Downloading commonmark-0.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (51 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 51 kB 10.1 MB/s            
Collecting pygments<3.0,>=2.0.1
  Downloading Pygments-2.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.1 MB 13.3 MB/s            
Collecting greenlet!=0.4.17
  Downloading greenlet-1.1.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (147 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 147 kB 45.7 MB/s            
Requirement already satisfied: typing>=3.6 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from sqlalchemy-jsonfield~=1.0->apache-airflow) (3.7.4.3)
Collecting requests>=2.26.0
  Downloading requests-2.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 63 kB 2.8 MB/s             
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=0.9.3->apache-airflow) (2.21)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from email-validator<2,>=1.0.5->flask-appbuilder<4.0.0,>=3.3.2->apache-airflow) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: dnspython>=1.15.0 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from email-validator<2,>=1.0.5->flask-appbuilder<4.0.0,>=3.3.2->apache-airflow) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Flask-Babel<3,>=1->flask-appbuilder<4.0.0,>=3.3.2->apache-airflow) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Babel>=2.3 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Flask-Babel<3,>=1->flask-appbuilder<4.0.0,>=3.3.2->apache-airflow) (2.7.0)
Collecting anyio==3.*
  Downloading anyio-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 79 kB 10.7 MB/s            
Collecting h11<0.13,>=0.11
  Downloading h11-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 54 kB 4.4 MB/s             
Collecting contextvars>=2.1
  Downloading contextvars-2.4.tar.gz (9.6 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting isodate
  Downloading isodate-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 41 kB 892 kB/s             
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.26.0->apache-airflow-providers-http->apache-airflow) (1.25.7)
Collecting immutables>=0.9
  Downloading immutables-0.16-cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (103 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 103 kB 75.1 MB/s            
Building wheels for collected packages: blinker, contextvars
  Building wheel for blinker (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for blinker: filename=blinker-1.4-py3-none-any.whl size=13451 sha256=fcf9e396978c821a6f95c3c4bb3fb02ae0f30a36d10c83b61918f46a55746ec9
  Stored in directory: /home/ec2-user/.cache/pip/wheels/4f/4a/93/c5ed8c11fedbe97fb8b8032b301eaa736248684b44087a7259
  Building wheel for contextvars (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for contextvars: filename=contextvars-2.4-py3-none-any.whl size=7665 sha256=ce680f0367b50496d8c842571ca00663a14b554010617caea24cd1b2175e7dc6
  Stored in directory: /home/ec2-user/.cache/pip/wheels/41/11/53/911724983aa48deb94792432e14e518447212dd6c5477d49d3
Successfully built blinker contextvars
Installing collected packages: immutables, zipp, contextvars, werkzeug, sniffio, greenlet, dataclasses, sqlalchemy, rfc3986, python3-openid, marshmallow, jsonschema, isodate, h11, charset-normalizer, apispec, anyio, requests, pytzdata, pygments, openapi-schema-validator, marshmallow-sqlalchemy, importlib-resources, httpcore, flask-wtf, commonmark, cffi, async-generator, tenacity, swagger-ui-bundle, sqlalchemy-jsonfield, rich, python-daemon, pendulum, openapi-spec-validator, marshmallow-oneofschema, inflection, httpx, gunicorn, flask-caching, flask-appbuilder, cryptography, clickclick, blinker, apache-airflow-providers-sqlite, apache-airflow-providers-imap, apache-airflow-providers-http, apache-airflow-providers-ftp, alembic, apache-airflow
  WARNING: Value for scheme.purelib does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10151>
  distutils: /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
  sysconfig: /home/ec2-user/softwares/etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages
  WARNING: Additional context:
  user = False
  home = None
  root = None
  prefix = None
  Attempting uninstall: zipp
    Found existing installation: zipp 0.6.0
    Uninstalling zipp-0.6.0:
      Successfully uninstalled zipp-0.6.0
  Attempting uninstall: werkzeug
    Found existing installation: Werkzeug 0.16.0
    Uninstalling Werkzeug-0.16.0:
      Successfully uninstalled Werkzeug-0.16.0
  Attempting uninstall: sqlalchemy
    Found existing installation: SQLAlchemy 1.3.11
    Uninstalling SQLAlchemy-1.3.11:
      Successfully uninstalled SQLAlchemy-1.3.11
  Attempting uninstall: python3-openid
    Found existing installation: python3-openid 3.1.0
    Uninstalling python3-openid-3.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled python3-openid-3.1.0
  Attempting uninstall: marshmallow
    Found existing installation: marshmallow 2.19.5
    Uninstalling marshmallow-2.19.5:
      Successfully uninstalled marshmallow-2.19.5
  Attempting uninstall: jsonschema
    Found existing installation: jsonschema 3.1.1
    Uninstalling jsonschema-3.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled jsonschema-3.1.1
  Attempting uninstall: apispec
    Found existing installation: apispec 1.3.3
    Uninstalling apispec-1.3.3:
      Successfully uninstalled apispec-1.3.3
  Attempting uninstall: requests
    Found existing installation: requests 2.22.0
    Uninstalling requests-2.22.0:
      Successfully uninstalled requests-2.22.0
  Attempting uninstall: pytzdata
    Found existing installation: pytzdata 2019.3
    Uninstalling pytzdata-2019.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pytzdata-2019.3
  Attempting uninstall: pygments
    Found existing installation: Pygments 2.4.2
    Uninstalling Pygments-2.4.2:
      Successfully uninstalled Pygments-2.4.2
  Attempting uninstall: marshmallow-sqlalchemy
    Found existing installation: marshmallow-sqlalchemy 0.18.0
    Uninstalling marshmallow-sqlalchemy-0.18.0:
      Successfully uninstalled marshmallow-sqlalchemy-0.18.0
  Attempting uninstall: importlib-resources
    Found existing installation: importlib-resources 1.5.0
    Uninstalling importlib-resources-1.5.0:
      Successfully uninstalled importlib-resources-1.5.0
  Attempting uninstall: flask-wtf
    Found existing installation: Flask-WTF 0.14.2
    Uninstalling Flask-WTF-0.14.2:
      Successfully uninstalled Flask-WTF-0.14.2
  Attempting uninstall: tenacity
    Found existing installation: tenacity 4.12.0
    Uninstalling tenacity-4.12.0:
      Successfully uninstalled tenacity-4.12.0
  Attempting uninstall: sqlalchemy-jsonfield
    Found existing installation: SQLAlchemy-JSONField 0.9.0
    Uninstalling SQLAlchemy-JSONField-0.9.0:
      Successfully uninstalled SQLAlchemy-JSONField-0.9.0
  Attempting uninstall: python-daemon
    Found existing installation: python-daemon 2.1.2
    Uninstalling python-daemon-2.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled python-daemon-2.1.2
  Attempting uninstall: pendulum
    Found existing installation: pendulum 1.4.4
    Uninstalling pendulum-1.4.4:
      Successfully uninstalled pendulum-1.4.4
  Attempting uninstall: gunicorn
    Found existing installation: gunicorn 19.9.0
    Uninstalling gunicorn-19.9.0:
      Successfully uninstalled gunicorn-19.9.0
  Attempting uninstall: flask-caching
    Found existing installation: Flask-Caching 1.3.3
    Uninstalling Flask-Caching-1.3.3:
      Successfully uninstalled Flask-Caching-1.3.3
  Attempting uninstall: flask-appbuilder
    Found existing installation: Flask-AppBuilder 2.3.4
    Uninstalling Flask-AppBuilder-2.3.4:
      Successfully uninstalled Flask-AppBuilder-2.3.4
  Attempting uninstall: alembic
    Found existing installation: alembic 1.3.1
    Uninstalling alembic-1.3.1:
      Successfully uninstalled alembic-1.3.1
  Attempting uninstall: apache-airflow
    Found existing installation: apache-airflow 1.10.15
    Uninstalling apache-airflow-1.10.15:
      Successfully uninstalled apache-airflow-1.10.15
Successfully installed alembic-1.7.6 anyio-3.5.0 apache-airflow-2.2.3 apache-airflow-providers-ftp-2.0.1 apache-airflow-providers-http-2.0.3 apache-airflow-providers-imap-2.2.0 apache-airflow-providers-sqlite-2.1.0 apispec-3.3.2 async-generator-1.10 blinker-1.4 cffi-1.15.0 charset-normalizer-2.0.12 clickclick-20.10.2 commonmark-0.9.1 contextvars-2.4 cryptography-36.0.1 dataclasses-0.8 flask-appbuilder-3.4.4 flask-caching-1.10.1 flask-wtf-0.14.3 greenlet-1.1.2 gunicorn-20.1.0 h11-0.12.0 httpcore-0.13.7 httpx-0.19.0 immutables-0.16 importlib-resources-5.4.0 inflection-0.5.1 isodate-0.6.1 jsonschema-3.2.0 marshmallow-3.14.1 marshmallow-oneofschema-3.0.1 marshmallow-sqlalchemy-0.26.1 openapi-schema-validator-0.1.6 openapi-spec-validator-0.3.3 pendulum-2.1.2 pygments-2.11.2 python-daemon-2.3.0 python3-openid-3.2.0 pytzdata-2020.1 requests-2.27.1 rfc3986-1.5.0 rich-11.2.0 sniffio-1.2.0 sqlalchemy-1.4.31 sqlalchemy-jsonfield-1.0.0 swagger-ui-bundle-0.0.9 tenacity-8.0.1 werkzeug-1.0.1 zipp-3.6.0
```

After executing the above command, I wanted to check the Airflow version and I got this error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pendulum'
```

So, I ran this command -

```
pip install pendulum
```

To my surprise, I got even more errors

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
apache-airflow 2.2.3 requires cryptography>=0.9.3, which is not installed.
apache-airflow 2.2.3 requires markupsafe>=1.1.1, which is not installed.
apache-airflow 2.2.3 requires psutil<6.0.0,>=4.2.0, which is not installed.
apache-airflow 2.2.3 requires pyyaml>=5.1, which is not installed.
apache-airflow 2.2.3 requires setproctitle<2,>=1.1.8, which is not installed.
apache-airflow 2.2.3 requires sqlalchemy>=1.3.18, which is not installed.
Successfully installed pendulum-2.1.2
```

It says that pendulum-2.1.2 is Installed, but the same error(No module named 'pendulum') appears when I check the airflow version

Any suggestions?

**Details** :

```
Airflow version upgrade from 1.10.15 to 2.2.3(latest version)
Machine used - Amazon EC2 instance
Python version - 3.6.8
pip version - 21.3.1
```

Comment: What was the output of the first `pip install -U apache-airflow` command? Something clearly went wrong there.

Comment: I edited the question and added the output of the command.

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing Airflow packages with a specific constraint file as described here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html#constraints-files

The file contains dependency packages in a tested setup for your Python version.

Comment: I tried this too, but the result is same

Comment: You probably did not follow it precisely. You MUST use constraints. Please check it again YOU MUST specify specific versions and you must specifiy both version of airlfow you want to install and python version in the constraitns.

Comment: @JarekPotiuk This is the command I used
pip install apache-airflow==2.2.3 \
  --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.2.3/constraints-3.6.txt"

Comment: If you're not accidentally using a virtual-env or something, all I could think of is that in your `airflow` command you might need to explicitly state the AIRFLOW_HOME variable if you haven't set it as env and it's other than default. Like `AIRFLOW_HOME=<home_dir> airflow version`. Also make sure you're using the correct user profile when installing the packages and running the command. Usually a dedicated 'airflow' user is created to run the software.